# Giving infinite as result when using matrix chain multiplication to find the efficient cost

Tags: javascript, algorithm, recursion, dynamic-programming, multiplication

I am trying to understand Matrix Chain Multiplication. Particularly the problem `Given a sequence of matrices, find the most efficient way to multiply these matrices together.`

I tried the following but it prints some infinite value for the result. What is it that I am doing incorrectly?

```js
const p = [1, 2, 3, 4, 3];

function mcm(m, i, j) {
 if (i >= j) return 0;
 else {
    let ans = Number.MAX_VALUE;
    let temp;
    for (let k = i; k < j - 1; k++) {
       temp = mcm(m, i, k) + mcm(m, k + 1, j) + m[i - 1] * m[k] * m[j];
       if (ans > temp) ans = temp;
    }
    return ans;
 }
}

console.log(mcm(p, 1, p.length - 1));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is in the end-condition for your `for` loop:

```
for (let k = i; k < j - 1; k++) {
```

It should be:

```
for (let k = i; k < j; k++) {
```

The reason is that `j` is *included* in the range to inspect, and so `k` should go up to and including `j-1`.

You are getting near Infinity because there are cases in your code where the loop performs no iterations at all (when `j-i==1`) and then the function will return `Number.MAX_VALUE`, which explains the output you get.